# Create singleton in swift 4 in a class having public init

Tags: ios, swift, singleton, swift4, init

I am having a public class in a different code like this -

```
public class Person {

   public required init() {}

}
```

This class is in a framework and cannot be modified.

Now the problem is I have been told to inherit from this class and create a singleton object of the new class

```
public class Jon: Person {
    public static var shared: Jon = Jon()
    required init() {}
}
```

But the required init is letting users create multiple instances of the class Jon.

Can anybody suggest on how to do this in swift 4.

Comment: Can you get rid of `required` keyword from `Person`? Otherwise it is impossible to `override` required initializer in your subclass.

Comment: I think the best you can do is make the required init `internal`. That was added into Swift 4.2: `Public classes may now have internal required initializers.`

Comment: But internal keyword just mean what you can't get access to this method from another module, which isn't our case as I understand.

Comment: Well if you were shooting for making it private for the reason that somebody accessing it in another module could initialize `Person` then that at least would be achievable using `internal`. If you need to protect your module as well from calling the `init` then yes, using `internal` wouldn't be able to accomplish that.

Comment: I was just saying that `private`, which would fit our bill, isn't valid for the required initializer.

Comment: Another approach would be to add `guard Jon.shared == nil else { fatalError("use Jon.shared") }` to the `init` to prevent the instantiation of another instance.

Comment: What do you mean by "But the required init is creating multiple instances of the class Jon?" How is the init itself creating multiple instances? Do you mean that callers are creating their own instances? Is that actually a problem? Just because there's a shared instance, do you have an actual *need* to prevent other instances from existing? (It is a very common pattern in Cocoa to have one shared instance without requiring there be only one instance in the system. See NotificationCenter and UserDefaults.)

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution to achieve this. Look into my solution hopefully it will serve your purpose.

```
public class ParentClass {

    public required init() {}

}




class SubClass: ParentClass {

    static let sharedInstance = SubClass(foo: "")

    @available(*, unavailable)
    required init() { }


    //You can change the init parameter as per your requirement
    private init(foo: String) {
        super.init()

        //Write your initialization code
    }
}
```

If you dont want to pass any argument to the init you can do something like this.

```
private init(_ foo: String? = nil) {
        super.init()

        //Write your initialization code
}
```

Now you initialize your object without passing any argument like

```
static let sharedInstance = SubClass()
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to use Composition rather than Inheritance as the design solution. Since the Person object is supposed to be singleton as well we make it immutable and initialise it in the private `init` method using the required init

```
public class Jon {
    static let instance = Jon()
    private init() {
        person = Person()
    }

    public let person: Person
}
```

And it can be used like this (with a `name` property for instance)

```
var jon = Jon.instance
jon.person.name = "John"
```

or Person could be made private and computed properties added to the singleton class

```
public class Jon {
    static let instance = Jon()
    private init() {
        person = Person()
    }

    private let person: Person

    var name: String? {
        get { return person.name }
        set { person.name = newValue}
    }
}
```

and then the name property is accessed directly

```
var jon = Jon.instance
jon.name = "John"
```